# How to pass json object as parameter from AngularJS front end to WebAPI method and retrieve values

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass data entered in AngularJS front end to webAPI and retrieve another set of data to populate on a grid. I am trying to pass data as JSON object to webAPI method. In WebAPI method, the parameter I am passing for the JSON object as a Class object.

I am not able to enter to the particular webAPI method when I am using [HTTPPost], but I am able to enter to the webAPI method when I am using [HTTPGet]. But in that case the class object which is the parameter in the webAPI method shows NULL value.

Can you please advise how to fix the issue.

**WebAPI**

```
namespace webAPITestProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("NewRoute")] 
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        retrieveEmployeeData empData = new retrieveEmployeeData();
        retrieveProductDetails prodDetls = new retrieveProductDetails();    

        [Route("http://localhost:212122/api/Values/GetEmployeeData?EmployerDetls=")] 
        [HttpPost]
        public DataTable getEmployeeData(HttpRequestMessage request,[FromBody] Employer empDetails)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable { TableName = "MyTableName" };
            dataTable = empData.getEmployeeData(empDetails);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

**AngularJS-Controller**

```
angular.module('Test.Employer')
    .controller('EmployerController', ['$scope','headerValue', '$http',
        function ($scope, headerValue, $http) { 
            var ipEmployerDetls = {                   
                EmployerName: "cherokee",
                Company: "ABC"                   
            };

            $http({ 
                url: "http://localhost:212122/api/Values/GetEmployeeData?EmployerDetls=",
                dataType: 'json', 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls), 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                } 
            }).success(function (response) { 
                $scope.object = response.data;
            }) 
                .error(function (error) { 
                    alert(error.Message); 
                });
})();
```

**Employer class**

```
public class Employer
{
    string _companyCode = "";
    string _employerName = "";
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return _companyCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _companyCode = value;
        }
    }

    public string EmployerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _employerName;
        }
        set
        {
            _employerName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, the **Route**

Don't include querystrings in the route to the endpoint, the querystrings are by default bound to the parameters in the method signature if you pass them.
Define the controller route with the `RoutePrefix` attribute and the method route with the `Route` attribute. The both will be combine at runtime to create the method
route, in this case `api/Values/GetEmployeeData`.

Then, the **Method parameters**

You don't need define the `HttpRequestMessage` as an parameter. You can get that through the HttpContext from within the method by just writing `HttpContext.Current`.

Finally, you are declaring the dataTable and then reasign it the line after. You should simple do the last.

So, try it like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Values")] 
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    retrieveEmployeeData empData = new retrieveEmployeeData();
    retrieveProductDetails prodDetls = new retrieveProductDetails();    

    [Route("GetEmployeeData")] 
    [HttpPost]
    public DataTable getEmployeeData([FromBody] Employer empDetails)
    {
        var dataTable = empData.getEmployeeData(empDetails);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: The name getEmployeeData looks more suited to be a GET request then a POST.

Also, make the get and set in the Employer class the newer, simpler syntax

```
public class Employer
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE
Your client should be

```
angular.module('Test.Employer')
    .controller('EmployerController', ['$scope','headerValue', '$http',
        function ($scope, headerValue, $http) { 
            var ipEmployerDetls = {                   
                EmployerName: "cherokee",
                Company: "ABC"                   
            };

            $http({ 
                url: "http://localhost:212122/api/Values/GetEmployeeData", 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: JSON.stringify(ipEmployerDetls), 
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
                } 
            }).success(function (response) { 
                $scope.object = response.data;
            }) 
                .error(function (error) { 
                    alert(error.Message); 
                });
})();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188029/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-hoglund-how-to-pass-json-object-as-parameter-from).